# How to run a .sql file in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm building the 'Contact me' section of my website, and I want to store in a database the user message. So, i discovery mysql and i created this code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messages;

CREATE TABLE messages (
    email TEXT,
    message TEXT
);

INSERT INTO messages (email, message) VALUES (
    'usersemail@gmail.com',
    'User message....'
);
```

the tutorial I saw was running the file with python, creating a .db file where it stored the data, with a library called sqlite3. How can I do it whit javascript?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: You cannot do this with just client-side JS. You need a server. Most websites use PHP hosting, which is probably what you have.

Comment: While SQLite is a self-contained library, MySQL requires a server process to operate.